# How to automate PST Export in Outlook

Tags: outlook, export, pst

I've seen similar questions asked but with no good answers.

I simply want to be able to automate the PST Export feature of Outlook. In other words, I want to be able to schedule a time when Outlook executes the Export to PST function (with specific parameters), without requiring any user interaction.

Is there any way to achieve this? VBA, PowerShell, .net application, third party app, etc are all acceptable solutions.

Thank you for any info or pointers!

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @w.stoettinger unfortunately, no.